# how to ignore the "the" in a product title ASP.NET/SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

When i return a list of product stating with the letter "A" it obviously returns all products that start with the letter "A".

I would also like to return all products that start with the letter "A" and products which also have "The" at the begining. I also would like to get a better idea of how the best way to do this is. Would you use purely MS SQL or pass over the parameters using ASP.NET?

For example, i currently return this when i search for products with the letter "R"

- Rocky
- Rocky 2

Sample code

```
 SELECT title
 FROM   dbo.product
 WHERE (title LIKE 'R%')
```

I would like it to return.. for example...

- The Rock
- Rocky
- Rocky 2

**UPDATE:** Thanks for all your help on this. I am going to investigate Full Text Search a little more. But for the intrum i will use...

```
  SELECT title
  FROM   dbo.product
  WHERE (title LIKE 'The R%') OR
        (title LIKE 'R%')
```

Comment: Would you want to exclude `Pieces from Reeses` from the resultset when searching for "R" products?

Comment: This is a difficult problem to solve without unwanted side-effects. For movie or book title databases, developers often adopt, and seek to enforce, a data-entry convention whereby the definite and indefinite articles "The" and "A" and "An" are removed from the front of a title and appended, e.g. "Bourne Redemption, The", so that the title will sort "properly".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To exclude specifically "The" from the front of the title:

```
SELECT title
FROM dbo.product
WHERE title LIKE 'R%'
OR title LIKE 'The R%'
```

This approach has the advantage of avoiding a leading wildcard, which breaks the index lookup.  If you have a list of leading words you would like to ignore, you would use a set of search strings, e.g., 'R%', 'The R%', 'A R%', 'the R%', etc.  (However, the IN list doesn't work with wildcards.)

Comment: Thanks, this could be a good measure to use while i investigate the full text search mentioned in another post :)... dammit why did i not think of doing this in the first place lol

Answer (score 4):

Try this one -

```
SELECT title
FROM dbo.product
WHERE title LIKE '%R%'
```

Comment: My specialty isn't SQL, what does the --<-- do? Would this also return items such as Foo Rock?

Comment: @Kevin DeVoe, this is the simple comment `--`.

Comment: I think this wouldn't work for him then. I assume he's looking for things that start with A, ignoring 'The' at the beginning.

Comment: In this situation, I think the best choice - `Full-Text Search`

Comment: yeah i agree with Devart, FTS looks to be the way forward.

Answer (score 4):

You'd want to say `where title like '%Rock%'`.

P.S. If you want to get all products that contain a word beginning with the letter R, you would do this:

```
  `where title like '% R%' or title like 'R%'`
```

Note the space in the first term. If you do not include the space, you get `Poptarts` too.

Answer (score 3):

if you simply want to return:

- The Rock
- Rocky
- Rocky 2

then use:

```
WHERE (title LIKE '%R%')
```

it should work.

if you want to do more complex things with SQL Server in regards to text search, have a look at Full Text search features of SQL Server.

Comment: I think Full Text Search will be the way forward... any good resources i can read up on please?